# How to retrieve information from a database and display it using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a database with 6 Nations rugby results and teams, and I want to get the data from the results database using AJAX and display on a php page. This is a page i'm using called getData.php

```
<?php

$year=$_GET['year'];

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($connection,"6nationsDB");


// for results
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM results WHERE 
year(`date`)='$year' ORDER BY rnd, date");
$rs = array();
$i=0;
while($rs[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
// do nothing ;-)
}

// for team details
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY id");
$rs2 = array();
$i=0;
while($rs2[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
{

}


mysqli_close($connection);

unset($rs[count($rs)-1]);  //removes a null value
// print("{ \"results\":" . json_encode($rs) . "}");
print("{ \"results\":" . json_encode($rs) . " , \"teams\":" . 
json_encode($rs2) . "}");
?>
```

Trying to access the select statements in getData.php to get data from the database

Browse.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css" type="text/css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div id="getData"></div>

<script type ="text/javascript">
dis();
function dis()
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET",  "getData.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("getData").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}

</script>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I've tried to do this for the past couple of hours but i'm not getting anywhere with it

Comment: Are you using jQuery? ..  There are a lot of example around to do it with that platform. Also, do you check your traffic. A browser like Firefox Developer Edition has a web console that lets you see your outgoing requests.

Comment: I've tried jQuery but I wasn't having any luck with it

Comment: And when do you call your `dis()` function ...  I suggest updating you knowledge first with internet resources. Youtube and other sources are plenty available.

Comment: I suggest you do use jQuery. It is overall easier than raw javascript. And then use the `jQuery.get()` method ... Call teh url and start with a simple `echo "hello world" to see it working. Also, initiate you javascript, ie `window.onload = function(){ ... }` or the jQuery [`$(document).ready({ ... })`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: as other says and also i want to notice you that your method of dealing with mysql is unsecure : your string here : `(`date`)='$year` that come directly from `$_GET['year']`  hackers could access your database from this easy like a breakfast ,  look over google for `(php Requests + mysqli)  security`.